# mongodb import from csv in nested schema

Tags: mongodb

I have csv file as

Date,dynmSpecMeta.regNo,dynmSpecMeta.vehRegNumber,path,distCovered,fuelConsumption
2017-10-02,AZRPN5786K,MH 32 AQ 3189,Route 10,10.8,1.15
2017-10-02,AYHPN5745L,MH 31 AQ 3474,Route 7,18.5,2.59
2017-10-02,AZRPN5783D,MH 33 AQ 1684,Route 14,11,1.48
2017-10-02,AZRPN5951P,MH 30 AQ 5833,Route 8,5,0.68

and so many rows...

I want to import it into already existing schema-

```
var vahNityaSchema = new Schema({

updated: { type: Date, default: Date.now},

dynmSpecMeta: {
    date: Date,
    vehRegNumber: { type: String, required: false, unique: true},   // ref to vahAchar
    path: { type: String, required: false, unique: true},           // ref to vahPath
    regNo: { type: String, required: false, unique: true},          // ref to vahSarthi

    distCovered: Number, 
    fuelConsumption: Number,
}
```

})

I am unable to import it with simple mongoimport into nested schema....
Please help...